# Why does char to int casting works and not char to Integer in Java

Tags: java

I was working on a problem when I encountered this.

```
(int)input.charAt(i) //works
(Integer)input.charAt(i) // Does not work
// input being a string
```

The first thought I have is primitives are treated differently and that is why this is not working. But then I find it difficult to understand why would they have a Integer Wrapper class in the first place.

**Edit:**
What are the advantages of having wrapper classes then? Is it just for not having a primitives presence and being more OO in design? I'm finding it difficult to understand how are tehy helpful. New doubt altogetehr.

Comment: Interesting. I would have thought that it could be auto boxed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right that primitives *are* treated differently. The following would work:

```
(Integer)(int)input.charAt(i);
```

The difference is that when the argument is an `int`, `(Integer)` *boxes* the integer. It's not actually a cast even though it looks like it. But if the argument is a `char`, then it would be a cast attempt; but primitives can't be cast to objects and therefore it doesn't work. What you *can* do is to first cast the `char` to `int` - this cast is okay since both are primitive types - and then the `int` can be boxed.

Of course, `char` -> `Integer` boxing *could* have been made working. "Why not?" is a good question. Probably there would have been little use for such feature, especially when the same function can be achieved by being a little bit more explicit. (Should `char` -> `Long` work too, then? And `char` -> `Short`? chars are 16-bit, so this would be most straightforward.)

**Answer to edit:** the advantage of wrapper classes is that wrapped primitives can be treated like objects: stored in a `List<Integer>`, for example. `List<int>` would not work, because `int` is not an object. So maybe even more relevant question would be, what are primitive non-objects doing in an OO language? The answer is in performance: primitives are faster and take less memory. The use case determines whether the convenience of objects or the performance of primitives is more important.

Comment: So won't using primitives in collections speed up performance?

Comment: @gizgok: There's no way to use primitives in collections because primitives aren't objects. That is, you can't construct a `List<int>`, it doesn't compile. Primitive *arrays* are objects though, so a `List<int[]>` would work, and yes, depending on what you do with it and how, it would be at least as or more performant as `List<Integer[]>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because Integer is an `Object`. and char is not. you cant cast a non Object thing to some Object.

Infact you cannot cast some Object to any other class Object which is not in the hierarchy of that Object.

eg you cannot do this

```
Integer g = (Integer) s;
```

where `s` is object of `String`.

Now why chat to int works, because every character is represented as unicode in java, so you can think of it as at backend char is a smaller version of int. (int is 32 bits and char is 16 bits)

Comment: True but I thought that auto boxing would have happened.

Comment: auto boxing is true only for ints. this means that you will not have to do explicitly casting when you are converting an int to Integer. @gizgok